# Where is the repository picker in my Git GUI?

Tags: windows, git, git-gui

I have just started using GIT and for some reason every single time I click to open GIT GUI I can't see the repo picker, it just goes to the repository screen and shows it's in C drive.

Does anyone know how to over ride this so I can pick my repo every time it opens like normally?

Thanks

Comment: use http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/ gitextensions instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the `git gui` command, it opens a repository determined by your current working directory. If you are outside a GIT_WORK_TREE, then you will see a dialog that allows you to select a repository.

If you're using some other tool, you will need to update your question to get a better answer.